# Buid App IOS in Monaca error: The platform "ios" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. ios not supported

Tags: ios, cordova, monaca

I build app in Monaca (under cordova@7.1.0, platforms: ios 4.5.2) error (Photo attached)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zGcV.jpg

Do you have any suggestion to solve this issue?

Many thanks !

Comment: attach the image properly and use text for error messages.

Comment: Link image error: https://i.imgur.com/R9rA2nh.jpg
Thanks!

Comment: Try to go to `cordova > platforms` via terminal and then run `sudo cordova platform update ios`. I have to do that everytime I do a git clone on my projects, it seems the `Api.js` is not required anymore but is still pointed to be missing if you don't update. Hope this solves it